# Swap 2nd and 6th char in a string using sed command

Tags: regex, sed, swap

I wrote a sed command to swap the second and sixth character in the numbers below.

I am getting the following error:

```
sed: file minor1.sed line 4: invalid reference \9 on `s' command's RHS
```

My sed command (script.sed):

```
s/\(.\){10}/\1\6\3\4\5\2\7\8\9\10/g
```

I am using sed -r -f script.sed Input.txt to run the command.

Input.txt -

```
8668797647
8884747424
3716706006
8662665588
```

Can anyone help me figure out why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you're only getting that error at `\9`, but here's an expression that does do what you're after, if you save it as a .sed and run it as you suggest:

```
s/(.)(.)(.{3})(.)/\1\4\3\2/
```

It does not have the `g` at the end, because you only want to replace the first match on each line anyway.

It matches: one character, one character, three characters and one character and then writes them back as the first match, the fourth match (sixth character), the third match (characters in between) and the second character. Effectively swapping the 2nd and 6th.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Do you happen to know why my original command wasn't working? Trying to figure out my mistake so I can avoid it

Comment: Your command repeated one group 10 times, but by the time it gets to replacement, only the last match will be available as `\1`, my command instead defines 4 distinct groups (and only repeats inside them), so it can refer to all 4. Not sure why the error singled out group 9 in your case, but that's probably due to how sed parses the replacement string. Your mistake was the assumption that repeating a group 10 times would give you 10 groups - instead it just repeats the expression in the group 10 times and retains the last match.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed -E 's/^\(.\)\(.\)\(...\)\(.\)/\1\4\3\2/'
```

This captures digits in groups numbered like this:

```
Input:  abcdefghij
Group:  123334  (the capture group of the digit above)
Result: afcdebghij
```

Only the first 6 digits are matched/replaced.